# Montecarlo estimate of a integrand from 0 to $\infty$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, monte-carlo, approximate-integration

I have a question about monte carlo estimation of integrals. Suppose I am told to estimate using monte carlo, the integral: $$f(y) = \int_{0}^{y}\frac{4}{1+x^{2}}dx$$ I want to estimate $f(\infty)$. I know that with some calculation, the exact values are given by $\pi$ and $2\pi$. However, there is some confusion with respect to defining the bounds and area given that the interval is now $\infty$. With an upper bound, such as $f(1)$ for example, I know I can generate random points from $[0,1]$x$[0,4]$ but I'm a bit confused as to what I should do in this case for $f(\infty)$.

I am told that: 
To deal with this, pick a value $x_{max}$ and approximate the integrand as zero for $x > x_{max}$. Keeping the number of samples fixed at 107, use `semilogx` to plot the absolute error of your estimate as a function of $x_{max}$ for $x_{max}$ = $10^{0}, 10^{1}, 10^{2}, . . . , 10^{7}$.

The biggest problem is that I am having trouble visualizing how to set $x_{max}$ and the points. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some help with respect to this as I am just barely grasping the understanding monte carlo estimation.

Thank you

Comment: Your run-time/precision will be HORRIBLE for large $y$ with the naive approach. You need importance sampling. Break up your integral into two parts: $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^{\infty}$. You can easily estimate the first one and for the second make $x=u^{-1}$ substitution (inspired by the primitive of $\frac 1 {x^2}\sim \frac 1 {1+x^2}$) to get $\int_0^1\frac 4{1+u^2}\,du$ and we even get the same integral as the first part - lucky coincidence.

Comment: @A.S. My guess would be that this assignment is actually intended to help them see an occasion when importance sampling is desirable. That said, it could be worse: with $x_{max}=(2n/\pi)^{1/3}$, the error scales as $n^{-1/3}$. Worse than generic Monte Carlo, but it still could be much worse than that.

Comment: @A.S. Also, after the analytical transformation you just did, you no longer need importance sampling: you can directly calculate $\int_0^1 \frac{8}{1+x^2} dx$ by the basic rejection sampling technique suggested in the OP. Here $10^7$ samples should give an error around $10^{-3}$.

Comment: @A.S. That said, I agree with you that this approach is quite a bit better: with my proposed $x_{max}$, I estimate the error at $8 (2n/\pi)^{-1/3} \leq 10 n^{-1/3}$. With this transformation approach I estimate it at $8 (\pi/4)^{1/2} (1-\pi/4)^{1/2} n^{-1/2} \leq 4 n^{-1/2}$. So at $10^7$ samples, this transformation approach gives an error which is about 20 times more accurate than the naive approach.

Comment: @Ian *Importance sampling* $\approx$ (Monte Carlo-specific name for) *u-substitution* // Indeed, the difference is not *that* drastic for $10^7$ samples. Capital letters were most about unbounded asymptotic difference than about specific run-times (which I didn't calculate) // If the intention was to introduce importance sampling, it'd be wise to isolate the issue from evaluating an integral over infinite domain (which seems like a conceptually sticky point for the OP). // OP, when you generate samples for $\int_0^1$, generate them from $[0,1]\times [2,4]$/use antithetical variables ($U,1-U$).

Comment: @Ian Can you clarify to me why is "rejection" method  for *integration* is so wide-spread in low level presentations when all it does, roughly speaking, is substituting $f(U)$ for $B(1,f(U))$ - equal in expectation, but clearly higher variance. Why take such teaching approach? Am I missing some bigger context where the difference is in favor of "rejection" method? (not talking about Metropolis-Hasting).

Comment: @A.S. 1. This sort of thing can show long runtimes when you don't do anything clever; indeed, this transformation method achieves an error estimate of about $0.0004$ with $10^8$ samples while the naive method still gives an error estimate of $0.01$ even with $10^9$ samples. Showing it with importance sampling *afterwards* can help motivate the idea. 2. Sampling from a rectangle and rejecting points lying above the density function is a simple method to visualize, and doesn't require any explanation of CDF inversion. Those are the only reasons I can think to teach it.

Comment: @A.S. Also you may as well write it correctly: the desired quantity is $a$, the random variable is $x_{max} y_{max} B$ where $B$ is Bernoulli with parameter $\frac{a}{x_{max} y_{max}}$. So the expectation is $a$, the variance is $x_{max} y_{max} a(x_{max} y_{max}-a)$, so the "signal to noise ratio" is $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x_{max} y_{max}(x_{max} y_{max}-a)}}$. That's not bad provided $x_{max} y_{max} - a$ is not too large.

Comment: @Ian I don't get the second part since what I am proposing requires no CDF inversion. I say (when everything is rescaled into $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ rectangle): generate $U$ and add $f(U)$ to the tally. Rejection method says: generate $U$ and add $B(1,f(U))$ to the tally. Same number of function evaluations but the "rejection" method has one extra random variable generated and possibly as much as $1/4$ of extra variance // Rejection's variance is $a(1-a)$. Variance of my (cheaper) suggestion is $\int_0^1 f^2-a^2<a-a^2$. In fact, the difference is exactly $\int_0^1 f(1-f)>0$ (as expected).

Comment: @A.S. Ah, now I understand what you were proposing. Yes, if both methods have to directly compute $f(U)$ then your proposed method is better. One advantage to the rejection approach can occur when one can determine whether $(x,y)$ is in the desired region without directly computing $f(U)$. For example this can be done to approximate $\pi$ by approximating the area of the solution to the inequality $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, without computing any square roots. The direct method would compute $4 \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$, which requires square roots. But yes, this is a rather contrived scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\int_0^\infty \frac{4}{1+x^2} dx = \int_0^y \frac{4}{1+x^2} dx + \int_y^\infty \frac{4}{1+x^2} dx$. Here $y$ is a parameter that you choose. To make this work by using the rejection sampling method that you are proposing, you need an analytical error estimate for the second term (because there is no uniform distribution on an infinite rectangle). A lower bound is of course zero; an upper bound is $\int_y^\infty \frac{4}{x^2} dx = \frac{4}{y}$. So you can calculate the original integral with an error tolerance of $\varepsilon$ by calculating the first piece to an accuracy of $\varepsilon/2$ with $y>\frac{8}{\varepsilon}$ (so that the second piece is also less than $\varepsilon/2$).

Comment: We are suggesting the same approach with different ways of dealing with the tail.  Mine is more accurate, yours is less work.  Mine will permit a lower $y$, which achieves accuracy in the Monte Carlo more quickly, but letting the computer run a little longer and not working the person so hard is also a reasonable approach.  I am glad we showed both.  +1

Comment: Thank you for your help, so given that I am to choose $x_{max}$ = $10^{0}, 10^{1}, 10^{2}, . . . , 10^{7}$, I would assume that this would be the value of $y$. So I'm guessing that the error would decrease (linearly/exponentially ?) in values of $y$

Comment: @RossMillikan I think you actually have a small calculus error in your answer; I think our answers are actually pretty much equivalent once that is correccted.

Comment: @PutsandCalls Yes, what I called $y$ is what you called $x_{max}$. And your error *should* scale as $y^{-1}$, provided your Monte Carlo is done accurately enough on the bounded part of the range of integration. But this will take longer for larger $y$.

Comment: You are right, but I am not sure it was a small error.  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Great! I will execute it on Matlab and hopefully everything scales according to $y^{-1}$. Thank you

Comment: @PutsandCalls Oh, now I see something interesting in your problem statement: you are expected to keep the number of samples constant. This means that by increasing $y$, you will *increase* the error in the bounded region and *decrease* the error from the tail. Consequently you should expect $y^{-1}$ scaling error for small $y$ and then later you should actually expect the error to *increase*. Estimating the turning point is not so simple; you would need to estimate how the variance and the rejection probability scale with $y$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, I will try to give it a shot, would it be possible for me to post the plot to see if it agrees with your intuition about it (if you have time)? Also, I'm assuming that I can take the sum of the 2 approximated separate integrals and then subtracting by the exact value ($2\pi$) to get the absolute error right ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls Sure. Also I was wrong: estimating the turning point is easy. Your random variable is $4yB$ where $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p=\frac{\arctan(y)}{y}$. (This isn't how you're sampling from it, but this is what it is.) So your variance is $16 y^2 p(1-p)$, which is roughly proportional to $y$. So the error is $O(\sqrt{y}/\sqrt{n})$. So you should need $O(y/\varepsilon^2)$ samples to get an error of $\varepsilon$, and with a fixed number of samples, your overall error is roughly $c_1 y^{1/2} + c_2 y^{-1}$.

Comment: @PutsandCalls Being even more explicit: with $y=(2 n/\pi)^{1/3}$, you should get an error on the order of $n^{-1/3}$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the advice Ian, I very much appreciate your help. I'm a bit uncertain about my results due to a slight mix up with the bounds of the interval. For the first integral, I defined my samples uniformly between [0,$x_{max}$] and then for the latter case, I defined my samples to be drawn uniformly from [$x_{max}$,$\infty$) with the given values of $x_{max} = 10^{0},10^{1}, ... 10^{7}$. Then I defined a value of $y$ uniformly on [0,4].

Comment: @PutsandCalls You shouldn't be doing any sampling from $[x_{max},\infty)$ at all. You are just treating that part of the integral as zero in this approach.

Comment: @Ian Ah I guess that was a bit of redundancy, no wonder my sum of the number of times that the 2nd sampling was less than $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ is 0 anyhow. Overall, it seems that my errors are decreasing in $y$ (which I'm not sure if it coincides with the fact that it should be $c_{1}y^{\frac{1}{2}}+c_{2}{y^{-1}}$. Once I count the number of times that the samples landed inside the function, would I need to multiply it by the area of the rectangle right?

Comment: @PutsandCalls Yes (and divide by the total number of samples). With $10^7$ samples your errors should turn around between $y=10^2$ and $y=10^3$.

Comment: @Ian I multiplied it by the area of the rectangle (which should be a function of $x_{max}$), which resulted in some insanely large errors for me... Which kind of makes me hesitant. Just to confirm, I am counting the number of given by $\frac{4}{1+x^{2}}$. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this

Comment: @PutsandCalls Sample $n$ points $(x,y)$ uniformly from $[0,x_{max}] \times [0,4]$. Count how many times you have $y \leq \frac{4}{1+x^2}$; call this $k$. Your approximation for the integral is then the total area, i.e. $4 x_{max}$, times the fraction of successes, i.e. $\frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is what I did but my plot as a function of $x_{max}$ ended increasing (I have shown it in the original post). but this kind of goes against what you said about the error being on the order of $n^{\frac{-1}{3}}$. Hope that you can take a look at it when you have time

Comment: @PutsandCalls With $x_{max}=(2n/\pi)^{1/3}$, your overall error will be on the order of $n^{-1/3}$. But in your problem you are holding $n$ constant and changing $x_{max}$. So this sort of behavior is actually to be expected: eventually you are computing the integral over the bounded region badly. (I'm not sure why it is as badly as that graph, though, I think you must be doing something wrong to get that graph).

Comment: Ah now I understand what you meant, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can split the integral into two pieces:  $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{1+x^{2}}dx= \int_{0}^{y}\frac{4}{1+x^{2}}dx+ \int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{4}{1+x^{2}}dx$, use Monte Carlo on the first and approximate the second by $\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{4}{x^{2}}dx=-\frac 4{x}|_y^\infty=\frac 4{y}$ You can bound the error on the second piece by (what does removing the $+1$ change?).  You should choose the breakpoint $y$ so the error caused by ignoring the $+1$ in the tail portion is about the same as the random error in your Monte Carlo.